# Spring cloud config security by application

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

How can I config different username/password for spring cloud config for each application.
I need that one application can't read the configuration of other application.
I can set an user/password but is for all:

```
security:
  user:
      name: account
      password: mypassword
```

Comment: Where did you put that configuration?

Comment: AFAIK spring cloud config server supports security to permit access, but doesn't limit the information for specific services. You might consider switching to consul, as spring cloud has official support for that, and consul offers ACL security, where you can define a ACL token to encapsulate config for particular services